# Wisconsin Governor Line Item Veto

Tags: constitutional-law, us-constitution

Famously, Wisconsin Governor Tony Evers tried to run a "line item veto" that essentially rewrites a law.

Is this legal? If it is easy to challenge it court, why haven't his political opponents?

[image]

EDIT: In theory, with this ability, the governor could write his own laws, by striking all but a few words that say whatever he wants.

Comment: The audacity to veto an em-dash.

Comment: This is unique to Wisconsin. It isn't a line item veto. It's called the "partial veto." I can say more tomorrow.

Comment: Technically an en dash, I believe.

Comment: "write his own laws, by striking all but a few words that say whatever he wants" See [WI Const V,10(1)(c)](https://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/constitution/wi/000231/000013/000001/000003), he can't combine letters to make words or combine parts of separate sentences, and it's not laws in general but appropriation bills.